# How can i print 5 digit after floating point in Swift 4, is there any shortest way?

Tags: iphone, swift, floating-point

I want to print 5 digit after point in Swift 4. In C language i can do it as .5f but now i can't. Have any shortest code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
String(format: "%.5f", 1.831831)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.